# How to move Tabs indicator to top when using react Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Simple Tabs sample, and I made some styles in tabs like this:

[image]

but I need to move indicator to top

just like this:

[image]

I can add the top border to MuiTab-root-selected, but nor I can find a way to remove the indicator...

this is [Simple Tabs sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/cbn97)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need customized tabs: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#customized-tabs

```
const StyledTabs = withStyles({
  indicator: {
    top: 0
  }
})(props => <Tabs {...props} TabIndicatorProps={{ children: <span /> }} />);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lt920